# Optimization with a linear and a max function

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization, linear-programming, nonlinear-optimization, operations-research

Consider the following optimization formulation:

$$\max \, c_1x - \sum_{i=1}^{n} c_i \max(x-a_i, 0) \\ x \geq 0 $$

where $a_i$ and $c_i$ are positive parameters.

I know this problem can be reformulated as an MIP. However, the problem seems to have a nice structure. Is there a way to solve it using another approach (e.g., line search) instead of casting the problem as a MIP?

Comment: What do you mean by $\max(x-a_{i})$?  $x$ is presumably a vector and $a_{i}$ is a scalar, right?

Comment: fixed. It is $max (x -a_i, 0)$. Yes, a_i is a scalar. x can be considered as a single decision variable.

Comment: The function to optimize is a piecewise linear function, with the "pieces" changing at $x = a_1, a_2, \cdots, a_n$. And because the maximum of a linear function in an interval is always given by one of the endpoints, all you need to check is $x = a_1, a_2, \cdots, a_n$.

Comment: If your problem were a bit more complex you also do not need binary variables because you could linearize the max expression with an auxiliary variable $y\geq 0$ and constraints $y\geq x-a_i$.

Comment: Is the $c_{1}$ in the first term the same constant as the $c_{1}$ in the sum, or a different constant (perhaps it could be called $c_{0}$)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll assume that the problem is

$f(x)=\max c_{0}x - \sum_{i=1}^{n} c_{i} \max(x-a_{i},0)$

The special case where $c_{0}=c_{1}$ is handled by the general solution given here.

Assume without loss of generality that the coefficients $a_{i}$ and $c_{i}$ are sorted so that

$0 < a_{1} \leq a_{2} \leq \ldots \leq a_{n}$.

The function $f(x)$ is concave and piecwise linear.  The derivative is discontinous at the points $a_{1}$, $a_{2}$, $\ldots$, $a_{n}$.

For $x<a_{1}$, $f(x)=c_{0}x$, and $f'(x)=c_{0}$.

For $a_{1} < x < a_{2}$, $f(x)=c_{0}x-c_{1}(x-a_{1})$, and $f'(x)=c_{0}-c_{1}$.

For $a_{k} < x < a_{k+1}$, $f(x)=c_{0}x-\sum_{i=1}^{k} c_{i}(x-a_{i})$, and $f'(x)=c_{0}-\sum_{i=1}^{k} c_{i}$.

For $a_{n}<x$, $f(x)=c_{0}-\sum_{i=1}^{n}c_{i}(x-a_{i})$, and $f'(x)=c_{0}-\sum_{i=1}^{n}c_{i}$.

If $c_{0}-\sum_{i=1}^{n}c_{i}>0$, then the function is unbounded as $x \rightarrow \infty$.

Otherwise, there is a point $a_{k}$ such that $f'(x)>0$ for $x<a_{k}$ and $f'(x)<0$ for $x>a_{k}$.  The maximum occurs at $x=a_{k}$.

Computationally, this problem can be solved by sorting the $a_{i}$, and then computing $c_{0}-\sum_{i=1}^{k} c_{i}$ for $k=1, 2, \ldots, n$.